# Bootstrap - How to ensure white space on far left and far right on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how to ensure I get white space/margin on the left hand side and right hand side when the page is viewed on a mobile phone?

My CSS is:

```
#maxCostSlider {
    max-width:304px;
    width:304px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-6px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #maxCostSlider,#sliderScale {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
      <img id="sliderScale" src="/assets/img/price slider 1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
      <input id="maxCost" data-slider-id='maxCostSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="10" data-slider-value="40" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This all looks good on a desktop and an iPad but when viewed on an iPhone the bootstrap-slider widget spans the entire width of the device. I would like to ensure there is always a margin of at least 20px either side of the two rows. Ideally the bootstrap-slider would scale to fit.

Comment: you could try out how it looks to use the `container` class instead of the `container-fluid` on small displays.

Comment: @muthan Changing the container will not help. Fluid always goes to the edge except at mobile width.

Comment: Which slider component are you using?

Comment: Need better insight in regards to the assets you're using, otherwise it'll be hard to mock up a solution.

Comment: The slider component is from: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without know the exact slider component you are using, but adding this to your CSS should work:

```
#maxCostSlider {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

However if you only want that to happen at mobile width, wrap it in a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #maxCostSlider {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The margin-left is working but the margin right seems to have no effect. When I shrink down my desktop window I get a jump in the alignment of the slider widget and the image that shows the scale. I am wondering if the problem is to do with the slider widget (which comes from: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider)?

Comment: I've made a slight tweak, the CSS should now apply to your slider rather than the input.

Comment: I now have the following CSS but still no joy with the right hand side:  #maxCostSlider {
  max-width:304px;
  width:304px;
  padding:0px;
  margin-left:-6px;
 }
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    #maxCostSlider,#sliderScale {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
 }

Comment: You are setting the width of the slider in your CSS to 304px, don't do that, or override it in the media query.

Comment: But I need to set the width of the slider or else it is not wide enough to match the size of the png scale. Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: Then make it smaller inside the media query?

Comment: Great! That has fixed the right hand margin issue. Now all that remains is that the scale image jumps to the left hand side below a certain viewport width and is no longer centred with the slider. Should I deal with that problem in another question?

Comment: Yes, different question :)

Answer (score 0):

For small device(sm) and extra small device (xs) you can call them separately.

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4"></div>
```

And another way you can do this by css.

```
@media (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #max-cost {
       padding-left: 20px;
       padding-right: 20px;
      }
}
```